# Realm Swift: Filtering objects by nested List property using IN predicate

Tags: ios, swift, realm, predicate

I have the following Realm Object structure:

```
class ParentObject: Object {
    let nestedObjects = List<NestedObject>
}

class NestedObject: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
}
```

Is it possible to filter `ParentObject`s to return only those that contain `NestedObject`s whose `id` matches one of those contained in an array?

I tried doing it this way:

```
let ids = [1, 2, 3]

let filtered = realm
    .objects(ParentObject.self)
    .filter("nestedObjects.id IN %@", ids)
```

But I'm getting this error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid predicate', reason: 'Key paths that include an array property must use aggregate operations'`.

Maybe I should try doing it with multiple `OR`s instead of `IN`?

Answer (score 6):

You want a predicate of `ANY nestedObjects.id IN %@`. The `ANY`/`ALL`/`NONE` modifier is important as it determines how many of the objects in the collection must match for the predicate to evaluate to true.

Comment: I was just about to answer it myself, but wow you are quick!! Great answer explaining the modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

new realm safe query syntax (10.19 I think) :
example looking for all parents with a nested object with id = myID and with a type = myType

```
let filtered = realm
        .objects(ParentObject.self)
        .where ({ parent in
            parent.nestedObjects.id == myId &&
            parent.nestedObjects.type == myType
        })
```

with old predicate syntax :

```
let filtered = realm
        .objects(ParentObject.self)
        .filter("ANY nestedObjects.id IN %@", [myId])
        .filter("ANY nestedObjects.type IN %@)", [myType])
```